# How Do I Filter By Git Branch In Jenkins Build History

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I run a job in TeamCity it filters the job history by branch.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/08/teamcity-7-1-control-the-flow/

[image: TeamCity Branch Label 2012]

The [Jenkins multi-branch plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) seemed to provide some of this, but it is now deprecated in favour of the jenkins pipeline plugin.

However, I am not using pipelines.

The multi-branch plugin also seems to be creating a new project for each branch instead of just filtering the existing project by branch.

Is there a way to provide this filtering feature in Jenkins in another way? (i.e. without changing my build to pipelines).